# Android .NET Trim function in Java?

Tags: java, .net, android, trim

In an Android app, I am looking for the functionality of the .NET string function [Trim('aaa')] which will trim off the text "aaa" off a string. I don't think this is natively available in Java and I haven't seen that functionality in Android Java textutil library.

Is there an easy way to have a Java app trim a set of characters from the string?

Comment: According to the .NET documentation, your description of how Trim works is incorrect.

Comment: Edited to a char array from string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regex trimming

The specification isn't clear, but you can use regular expression to do this.

Here's an example:

```
    // trim digits from end
    System.out.println(
        "123a456z789".replaceAll("\\d+\\Z", "")
    );
    // 123a456z

    // trim digits from beginning
    System.out.println(
        "123a456z789".replaceAll("\\A\\d+", "")
    );
    // a456z789

    // trim digits from beginning and end
    System.out.println(
        "123a456z789".replaceAll("\\A\\d+|\\d+\\Z", "")
    );
    // a456z
```

The anchors `\A` and `\Z` match the beginning and end of the input respectively. `|` is alternation. `\d` is the shorthand for the digit character class. `+` is "one-or-more-of" repetition specifier. Thus, the pattern `\d+\Z` is regex-speak for "sequence of digits at the end of the input".

#### References

- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

---

#### Literal trimming

If you just want a literal suffix/prefix chopping, then no regex is required. Here's an example:

```
public static String chopPrefix(String s, String prefix) {
    if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return s.substring(prefix.length());
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
public static String chopSuffix(String s, String suffix) {
    if (s.endsWith(suffix)) {
        return s.substring(0, s.length() - suffix.length());
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
public static String chopPresuffix(String s, String presuffix) {
    return chopSuffix(chopPrefix(s, presuffix), presuffix);
}
```

Then we can have:

```
    System.out.println(
        chopPrefix("abcdef", "abc")
    ); // def

    System.out.println(
        chopSuffix("abcdef", "ef")
    ); // abcd

    System.out.println(
        chopPresuffix("abcdef", "cd")
    ); // abcdef

    System.out.println(
        chopPresuffix("abracadabra", "abra")
    ); // cad
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [trim](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) or [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll).